# Showing symbol even in case of polygon size is small in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

I need to show at least one symbol (ideally on the center) on a polygon even if its size is small like in the picture below. In ArcGIS we succeeded but we need it on QGIS.
Updated to make the question more clear. In below picture scale is 10,000 and every polygons have symbols, ok, the polygon with number 15 is not ideal.

[image]

When we change scale to 25,000 symbols of some polygons doesn't show its symbols. I think it is because of view size of polygons is small to show it, at least qgis decided like that. I need to show at least one symbol on polygon in that case.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: How are you applying the current style? how big is the image you are using?

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I applied the "single symbology". When a map's scale is less than 10,000, symbology disappears on a polygon.

Comment: Please provide screenshots at different scales, showing your problem, as well as a screenshot of your current settings.

Comment: @Erik Updated question, added some screenshots

Comment: You could use the Point on Surface tool to create a temporary points layer which would have your symbol on it.

Comment: Thank you @johns. I solved an issue using rule based  ' bounds_width($geometry) < (@map_scale / 5)' filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have doubtless discovered, the `Displacement` for a point pattern fill is relative to the boundary, while in your use case you would like it relative to the centroid ("give me a symbol at the centroid and as many others as fit").

To achieve something comparable, I have in the past done the following, which starts off pretty simple but could get complicated if your geometries are:

1. One symbol layer with a widely spaced point pattern fill, as you have now.
2. Add a 2nd symbol layer with a centroid fill with the same symbol.
3. For each of the two symbol layers, set `Enable symbol layer` to be data-driven, conditioned on an expression deciding whether the polygon is big enough. If yes, symbol layer 1 will be on and 2 off, and the reverse if it's small.

The issue becomes what this "big enough" expression should be. In my case, my polygons are never too long and thin, and my pattern fill symbol spacing is square and of a fixed `Distance` in map units. So a simple `$area <` or `>` a fixed number is good enough. However, if your geometries are more complicated, you might need to write a more complex conditional expression comparing `bounds_height` and `bounds_width` to the pattern fill symbol `Distance` and actual symbol dimensions. (Holes add yet more complexity).

If you do need to do the latter, and for multiple layers and/or you expect to make changes to your symbology, I'd suggest encapsulating the logic in a custom expression function, and the symbol spacing parameter in a layer variable, to avoid things getting out of sync.

**Editing to add**: If your symbol size is in pixels, you might need to convert your polygon size expression from map units to pixels. Assuming your map units are metres, the following should give the number of metres in one pixel:

```
@map_scale / 1000 * 25.4 / coalesce(@layout_dpi,96)
```

This is a bit of a kludge based on the variables QGIS provides access to in expressions. The `/1000 * 25.4` converts from metres to inches. Dividing by `@layout_dpi` then gives number of map metres in one pixel. Unfortunately, that variable only exists in the context of a map layout, and I'm not aware of a corresponding variable for the screen dpi in an on-screen map canvas. But in my experience (on Windows), that is either 96 or 120 (irrespective of what the physical screen dimensions actually are) so this hard-codes that in. `@coalesce` picks the first entry if not null, otherwise the 2nd.

UPDATED by TS:
After playing with parameters `bounds_width($geometry) < (@map_scale / 5)` I think I got a solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Houska for your reply. Your point of view is the first solution I tried to implement, but my problem, in this case, how to determine the size of the polygon depending on the scale? bounds_height and bounds_width functions return actual size, not view size.

Comment: @kalempir, edited my answer to suggest how to get around this.

Comment: I accept your solution but added a function I used and some screenshots as solution results. Thank you very much.